# Is 'in the now' a meaningful phrase?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage

Can I use it in the following sentence:

> You may need my services **in the now**, or perhaps two months later.

With *in the now* meant to be used in lieu of *immediately*.

Is this correct use of the phrase? Or is it an altogether incorrect phrase?

I tried to find anything useful on Google, but I couldn't

Comment: What does your research show about "in the now"? Have you tried to Google it? Your question reads more like a request for proof-reading unless you include your own research and explain why you need to use "in the now".

Comment: @Rathony normally you'd be right but i just googled the phrase and was surprised to not find any clear definitions popping up - just lots of pages offering to help you "live in the now" etc.  Which isn't to say it's not defined *somewhere*, just that it's not obvious.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I can't agree with your comment more. But, do you see any reason why the OP needs to use "in the now" in the example sentence? +1 for your answer.

Comment: As mentioned by @MaxWilliams, I could not find anything useful on google. That's the reason I posted it here.

Comment: It would be better if you just write "I tried to find anything useful on Google, but I couldn't" in the future when you ask a question. It reduces the chances of your question being closed as off-topic. Please see the edit.

Comment: @Rathony well, i could see how "in the now" and "at present" (for example) might seem logically synonymous to someone who doesn't have English as their first language, and how that could cause confusion.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Learners learn how to use the word "now" at the elementary level. It's possible learners could find the phrase such as "in the now", but why attempting to use it when you don't know the meaning when there are other simple expressions as you suggested?

Comment: @MaxWilliams Do you mean the edit doesn't improve the post?

Comment: @Rathony are you asking me why the OP got confused?  I don't know, people get confused, that's why this site exists.

Comment: @MaxWilliams No, the site doesn't exist to help people who are confused. The site exists to help those who ask proper **on-topic** questions in accordance with the guidelines. I think you are misunderstanding the purpose of this community. What does it mean? Is it an incorrect phrase? type of questions are off-topic and should not be answered.

Comment: Why did you vote my answer up then?  :)  Anyway, it's answered, let's not argue.

Comment: Well, you answered the question with proper reference and research. Upvoting an answer has nothing to do with whether the question is on-topic or off-topic. If you move your mouse over "upvote mark" it says **This answer is useful**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be "in the now" means to be *"completely focussed on what is happening to you now, not thinking about the past or future or anything which isn't immediately around you."*

That is, it's a way of describing someone's **attentional state**.  It is alternatively referred to as "living in the moment", or the state of "mindfulness".  It is often linked to Buddhism, meditation and various relaxation techniques.  eg http://tinybuddha.com/blog/living-in-the-now-when-its-stressful-4-mindfulness-tips/

You would **not** use it in the context you describe - you would say *"at present"* or perhaps just *"now"*.

Comment: I think *in the now* typically occurs in the kind of written contexts (transcendentalism, relaxation techniques, etc.) you refer to, but when it comes to everyday conversational contexts, the version I always hear is along the lines of *I don't worry about the future. I'm only interested **in the here and now**.*

Comment: It's always *in the **here** and now*, in my experience. Of course, *in the now* is understandable, but I don't hear it.

Comment: *"In the here and now"* is a completely separate expression to *"in the now"*.  The former really means "pertaining to the situation at present", whereas the latter is a way of describing an individual's mental state.