# Can we use "of the now" with the verb?

Tags: meaning, grammar, vocabulary

I found this phrase in the [Vogue article](https://www.vogue.com/article/bad-bunny-style-overalls-sunglasses-gucci):

> His style, with its healthy punch of dork factor, **is of the now** in a
>   way that is similar to Post Malone’s very self-aware, disheveled,
>   sleazy look.

Isn't phrase "of the now" used with nouns, e.g. 'music of the now', 'artist of the now'?
I googled it and found 17 matches, which I do not trust entirely. 
Does it sound natural to you to say "is of the now"?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332494/is-in-the-now-a-meaningful-phrase

Answer (score 1):

It is an informal expression, used to refer to a current trend, fashion etc.

***[Now:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/now)*** 
informal

> of the moment; fashionable.
>
> - the now look is street fashion.

(Collins Dictionary)